# how to execute a bash script when someone connects to the ssh server (freebsd)

Tags: bash, ssh, freebsd

There is a freeBSD server that has a script on bash. The script analyzes the log file of ipfw (for unauthorized access to ssh) and in case of damage sends the message to the mail. Everything works if the script is placed in cron. But how to make the script work in real time? The idea was to launch a script for the event. So if someone tries to connect to the server by ssh, then it will be a script. But how to implement it?  P.S. Test task. About fail2ban with its ability to send mail know

Comment: More information would be helpful.  Do you want the script to run as soon as `ssh` connects, or only after a successful login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sshd` can be run as a stand-alone service, or from `inetd`.  If you run it from `inetd` you can write a simple wrapper around the /usr/bin/sshd binary to do whatever you'd like when an `ssh` connection is made:

```
# cat /root/bin/sshd.sh
#!/bin/sh
logger -i -p auth.info "Someone is trying to ssh in"
exec /usr/sbin/sshd "$@"
# ls -l /root/bin/sshd.sh
-rwx------  1 root  wheel  204 Jul 11 13:32 bin/sshd.sh*
# grep ^ssh /etc/rc.conf
sshd_enable="no"
# grep ^ssh /etc/inetd.conf
ssh     stream  tcp     nowait  root    /root/bin/sshd.sh       sshd -i -4
```

Bear in mind that mucking with `ssh` can potentially weaken your security, rather than strengthening it, as you are trying to do.  A dedicated product (such as Fail2Ban) may be a better solution.

Also, running a script on every `ssh` connection start-up could be expensive, if you're receiving connections at a high rate.  As before, this could chew up system resources and lead to a denial-of-service.  Running your cron job once a minute, or once every five minutes might be preferable in the sense that it puts only a minimal, constant load on the system.  The one-script-per-connection model increases the load in direct proportion to the pressure of the `ssh` attack.